# Open graph meta tag with facebook's url

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

I have a iframe tab where my open graph url tag is `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.facebook.com/myfacebookpageusername"/>`.

I have a comment box in that iframe that displays following error: Warning: http://example.com/linktofolder is unreachable.

I have set up all the info on facebook application setup like app domain, canvas url, namespace and etc. When I put link through facebook debugger I get following error: Error Scraping Page:  Facebook Can't Crawl Itself. Sorry!

I already have one page where my og:url tag is directed to facebook page, and it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `href` for Comments Social plugin (or `data-href`, depends on way you embed the comments) to real URL that is publicly accessible.

Also you should be aware of the fact that specifying `og:url` means that this page will be crawled instead of the page you have that meta tag.